# How to automatically crop and cut an image into several images using ImageMagick?

Tags: images, photos, imagemagick, crop

How to automatically crop and cut an image into several images using ImageMagick?

Hello,

Let's say I have an image with four circles of slightly different shape like so:

```
O o
o O
```

Is there a way to make ImageMagick automatically crop, cut and save the picture into four images like so:

```
Pic 1: O
Pic 2: o
Pic 3: o
Pic 4: O
```

Vesa

Update: I would prefer if an algorithm automatically figured out which parts of the image are most likely to belong together and crop accordingly. I think Inkscape has some kind of algorithm like that.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply need the images split into four ordered parts, you can use tile cropping like so:

```
convert -crop 2x2@ -scene 1 image.jpg cropped_%02d.jpg
```

This will split the image into four [roughly equal tiles](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_equal) numbered from `01-04`, from upper left to lower right.

Comment: Update: I would prefer if an algorithm automatically figured out which parts of the image are most likely to belong together and crop accordingly. I think Inkscape has some kind of algorithm like that.